# Exception Handling Help Xcode 4.6

Tags: objective-c, exception, error-handling, xcode4.6

Hello I am pretty new to programming but I have been following a few tutorials in Objective C. I just came across a problem in a Exception Handling tutorial and well, my code didn't work the same way.

First of all this is my code in main:

```
#import  < Foundation/Foundation.h> 
#import "Numz.h"

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]){

@autoreleasepool {

    Numz *n = [[Numz alloc]init];
    @try {
        [n thisisgoingtogetanerror] <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< error on this line      
        }

    @catch (NSException *e) {
            NSLog(@"you got an error in your program");
        }
        NSLog(@"this is code aftr the error");
   }

   return 0;
}
```

The error above says

> no visible @interface for 'Numz' declares the selector
>   'thisisgoingtogetanerror'

My interface and implementation are created but have no variables or methods created inside, but isn't that why I need to handle the error in the first place?
Also, I can't get any kind of console view either, the build just fails and points me at that error.

It *might be* some settings in xcode 4.6 that I need to change but I can't get the code to run and handle the error. I have looked online and can't find any answers.

Any help would be great.

Comment: well without a semicolon I don't think that is going to compile with any combination of compiler flags..

Comment: This is not really related to xcode. No Objective-C compiler would ever compile that (at least raise a warning in non-ARC projects) regarless of the IDE that you may use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compiler is complaining because you are calling a method that it has not seen a declaration of ever.

Change it to (assuming `Numz` is not a subclass of `NSArray` nor implements the `count` method): `[n count];`.

Note that you should *never use exceptions for flow control*.  That is, you should not `@throw` an exception and then use `@catch` to process the exception and continue execution.  Exceptions in iOS/Cocoa are only used to indicate unrecoverable errors.

Try this:

```
@interface NSObject(Badness)
- (void)methodBadness;
@end
```

Then call that method in your code.  Compiler shouldn't warn, runtime should @throw.

Comment: I am still confused because isn't that the point of error handling? It sees an error but it doesn't handle it like I want it too. Again I am a noob and I don't understand what you mean by flow control. I also tried 'count' and got the same error...

Comment: In Cocoa/iOS, throwing exceptions to then catch and recover is *not* how you do recoverable error handling.  This is completely unlike Java.

Comment: I figured out if I turn off Automatic reference counting it will run the code like I want it too.....not sure why though, any thoughts?

Comment: Yes, the non-ARC compiler allows constructs to compile that the ARC compiler treats as errors.  Most likely because they really should be errors.

Answer (score 0):

Exception handling is used for errors/exceptions at **runtime.** But the error you get occurs at **compile time**

You can cause a runtime error through something like this:

```
@interface RuntimeError : NSObject
+ (void)cause;
@end

@implementation RuntimeError
+ (void)cause {
    NSAssert(NO, @"This is a runtime error caused through a assertion failure")
}
@end

// Call it with
//     [RuntimeError cause]
// inside the @try-Block
```